# SOCP formulation from a convex constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Suppose I have the constraint set

$$\{x: a_1\|x-b_1\|_2-a_2\|x-b_2\|_2\leq t\}$$

where $a_1,a_2\geq 0$. I know that the function

$$f(x)=a_1\|x-b_1\|_2-a_2\|x-b_2\|_2$$

is convex (it is given that $f$ is convex) and, thus, any single constraint in the above set is an epigraph and, thus, convex. How can I reformulate the above constraint into an SOCP?

Is it correct to write it as follows?

$$\{x,w,v; a_1w-v\leq t, \|x-b_1\|_2\leq w, \|x-b_2\|_2\leq v\}$$

I am unsure about this as there is a negative sign with $v$. Any help would be really great.

Comment: Your function $f$ isn't convex in general.  What special conditions on $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, $b_{1}$, and $b_{2}$ make it convex?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I agree in general $f$ is not convex, suppose we already know that it is convex, then can we formulate it as an SOCP? The constant $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are fixed such that $f$ is convex.

Comment: The only conditions that make this work that I'm aware of are that $a_{1}>a_{2}$ and $b_{1}=b_{2}$ so that $f(x)=(a_{1}-a_{2})\| x-b_{1} \|$.  If that's the case, then you can use a standard SOCP formulation.

Comment: @BrianBorchers For an example, let $f(x)=4\|x-4\|_2-0.2\|x\|_2$ is convex. But how to write it as an SOCP constraint.

Comment: Where did $f(x)$ come from originally?  If you're given such a function how can you verify that it's convex?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I checked it in MATLAB. It is coming like a piece-wise linear function. I could not explicitly prove it because of the negative sign. In particular, $f(x)$ is just a function that I gave to show its existence.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to write it as:
>
> $ \left\{x,w,v \; | \; a_{1}w−a_{2}v \leq t, \|x−b_{1} \| \leq w, \| x-b_{2} \| \leq v \right\}$.

No, this doesn't work.  For example, if $a_{1}=4$, $b_{1}=4$, $a_{2}=0.2$, $b_{2}=0$, then

$x=1000$, $t=0$ doesn't satisy the original constraint, but

$x=1000$, $t=0$, $w=1000$, $v=1000000$, satisfies the proposed equivalent constraints.